# How do you install fonts to a Wordpress site?

Tags: html, wordpress, fonts, web, webfonts

I am making a music blog and I'd like to be able to use BebasNeueRegular on my Wordpress site. Obviously, this is possible considering [goldenscissors](http://goldenscissors.info/2012/07/27/telepopmusik-smile-natural-high-remix/) does it on their site (the titles for the widgets on the side and the title of the post are both using BebasNeueRegular).

I did a Google search for this, and only found how to install Google Web Fonts to Wordpress, but BebasNeueRegular is not a Google Web Font. Any help?

P.S. you can download the font [here](http://theultralinx.com/2011/10/bebasneueregular-font-download.html).

Comment: leonbloy below has the right answer, but just let me caution you that it is very easy to go overboard with custom fonts. Exercise restraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about [font-face](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/).

In your example, you can see by yourself this fragment in the style.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');

}
```

Comment: I read, and am still a bit confused. On that download page (and all the others I found), there is only an otf if the file, not eot, woff, tff, etc. I tried to see if I could download the files from my example, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Example: I tried going to http://goldenscissors.info/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot and it was not found.

Comment: jas7467...you can convert the font to necessary formats using this tool: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator/